# set FAB anchor gravity dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

I need to be able to change the `app:layout_anchorGravity="center"` of the FAB from `center` to `bottom|start` from the code.
I've found this example:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams p = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
p.setAnchorId(xxxx);
fab.setLayoutParams(p);
```

but it's for setting the anchor and not the anchor gravity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams` class has the `anchorGravity` field for that. For example:

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams();
lp.anchorGravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | GravityCompat.START;
fab.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Same thing in Kotlin**

```
        (rightUglyBox.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)
                       .anchorGravity 
                                     = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL or Gravity.LEFT;
```

*Works on all layout not just FAB